# modal se visualiza por detrás de otro modal

Tags: modal, bootstrap

tengo un problema con una ventana modal en boostrap
el problema es que son 3 ventanas modales, 2 de las ventanas se muestran correctamente , pero 1 se muestra detrás de la ventana modal principal.

imagen ventana que se muestra bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

imagen de ventana que se muestra detrás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca el codigo del modal

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modalVerReserva" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalMantenedorVuelosAgregarTramoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content modal-lg">
<div class="modal-header bg-primary">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="modalMantenedorVuelosAgregarTramoLabel">DETALLE VUELO</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cerrar">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body modal-md">
<div class="left container-fluid">
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container-fluid col-sm-3">
<input type="text" id="idVerReservaAjax"class="form-control">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="verReservaGuiaAjax()">Ver</button>
<div class="container-fluid" id="resultadoReservaGuia">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

y este es el botón para ejecutar el modal

```
<button type='button' size=1 class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalVerReserva' data-placement='left' title='Datos Cliente'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button>
```

Por favor su ayuda.

Comment: Estimados por favor su ayuda , necesito que el moda se muestre delante de los demas modal por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tengo algunas aplicaciones que utilizan muchos Modals, y tenia ese mismo problema, mi solucion fue poner este codigo que encontre en una pagina dejo el enlace al final

```
(function($, window) {
    'use strict';

    var MultiModal = function(element) {
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.modalCount = 0;
    };

    MultiModal.BASE_ZINDEX = 1040;

    MultiModal.prototype.show = function(target) {
        var that = this;
        var $target = $(target);
        var modalIndex = that.modalCount++;

        $target.css('z-index', MultiModal.BASE_ZINDEX + (modalIndex * 20) + 10);

        // Bootstrap triggers the show event at the beginning of the show function and before
        // the modal backdrop element has been created. The timeout here allows the modal
        // show function to complete, after which the modal backdrop will have been created
        // and appended to the DOM.
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            // we only want one backdrop; hide any extras
            if(modalIndex > 0)
                $('.modal-backdrop').not(':first').addClass('hidden');

            that.adjustBackdrop();
        });
    };

    MultiModal.prototype.hidden = function(target) {
        this.modalCount--;

        if(this.modalCount) {
           this.adjustBackdrop();
            // bootstrap removes the modal-open class when a modal is closed; add it back
            $('body').addClass('modal-open');
        }
    };

    MultiModal.prototype.adjustBackdrop = function() {
        var modalIndex = this.modalCount - 1;
        $('.modal-backdrop:first').css('z-index', MultiModal.BASE_ZINDEX + (modalIndex * 20));
    };

    function Plugin(method, target) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var data = $this.data('multi-modal-plugin');

            if(!data)
                $this.data('multi-modal-plugin', (data = new MultiModal(this)));

            if(method)
                data[method](target);
        });
    }

    $.fn.multiModal = Plugin;
    $.fn.multiModal.Constructor = MultiModal;

    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(document).multiModal('show', e.target);
    });

    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(document).multiModal('hidden', e.target);
    });
}(jQuery, window));
```

[Pagina de donde obtuve el código original](https://www.bootply.com/UpIj9AwV86)

Comment: Gracias  , una consulta, este código de jquery lo dejas en la pagina donde esta el modal? y el id del modal donde lo asocio al código de jquery?

Comment: Si, lo vas a agregar en la pagina donde tengas el modal, te recomiendo que veas el ejemplo. Saludos.

Comment: Ah, y con respecto a tu otra pregunta, no necesitas mas que agregar el código. No necesitas modificar lo que ya tienes.

Comment: si ya me di cuenta muchas gracias